# SQL Queries in Objective C

Tags: mysql, sql, objective-c

I've recently dived into the Objective C world and OSX programming.

One thing I am struggling to figure out how to do is how to execute simple SQL queries.

I've been coding in PHP for years and I'm used to the simple habits of:

```
mysql_connect(host, user, pass);
$query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM `somedb`.`sometable`);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print($row['column1']);
    ...
    print($row['column5']);
}
```

or something along the lines of that. *(Side note: I don't use the monstrous classic mysql statements anymore. I use PDO. For purposes of demonstration of logic and simplicity I used it to easially convey my point on what I roughly need to do in ObjC. Don't shoot me down for using it in the example :P)*

Is there any way at all to be able to **execute a similar set of functions in Objective C?** Simply to connect to a remote MySQL server on a remote machine and either `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` or `DELETE` rows?

Comment: Mysql is not directly built into iOS/OSX. You will either need to find a mysql library, or wrap your mysql calls into a server and call into that server from your iOS/OSX code. If your using OSX you can get the mysql c library working pretty easily using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). You should also know that you cannot redistribute (embed) most mysql library in your app due to oracle licensing terms.

Comment: @Zenox I'm aware of having to use an external library to be able of using SQL queries within iOS/OSX. With homebrew, say for OSX would I be able to export the application as a .app file and run it on any computer without the homebrew libraries installed on that machine? Does it bundle it with the .app file?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do ?

You can use Webservices(WS), for example a basic one which selects rows from your DB, then you transfom it in JSON.

You can use this function:
http://de3.php.net/json_encode

Then in you iOS app, you can call this WS then you can parse the JSON returned.

Finally, you can store what you parsed from the JSON returned with SQLite.

For more, you really should read those tutorials :

- [Tutorial to write PHP WS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)
- [Tutorial which uses a powerful library
  to parse JSON in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

Hope it helps...

PS: There is also CoreData to store data in the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eventDb.db"]];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &eventDb)==SQLITE_OK) { { {

    NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" INSERT INTO  EVENT(ENAME,ETIME,TIMAGE) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",_eventLbl.text,time,name];

       const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];

          sqlite3_prepare_v2(eventDb,insert_stmt,-1,&statement,NULL);

            if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) {

                NSLog(@"added");
            }
            else {

                NSLog(@"fail to added");  
            }
 } } }
```

- List item

Comment: - (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path=[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    return path;
    
    
}

Answer (score -1):

```
//database creation
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eventDb.db"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];  const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &eventDb)==SQLITE_OK)
    {    char *errmsg;
        const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENT(EVENTID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ENAME TEXT,ETIME TEXT,TIMAGE TEXT)";
        if(sqlite3_exec(eventDb,sql_stmt,NULL,NULL,&errmsg)!=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"falied");
        }
        sqlite3_close(eventDb);
          }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to open/create database");
    }
}
```

Comment: - (IBAction)uploadButton:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)setTime:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    timeFormatter.dateFormat =@"HH:mm:ss";
    NSString *dateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: _datePcker.date];
    time=dateString;
    
}

Comment: -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *id1=@"id";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell1=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:id1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
        event *n=_arr[indexPath.row];
       UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:10];
    titleLabel.text=n.eventname;

Comment: NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self documentsPathForFileName:n.eventImagename]];
   
    UIImageView *titleImage = (UIImageView *)[cell1 viewWithTag:20];
    titleImage.image=  [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];;
    return cell1;
    
}

Answer (score -1):

```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
       return 1; }
   -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [_tool count]; }
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       static NSString *myId=@"myID";
       UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myId];
       if (cell==nil)
       {
           [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"royalkitCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell=_toolCell;
           cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
       }
       NSString *tname=[_tool objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       _toolLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
       _toolLabel.text=tname;
       return  cell;
       }
```

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    _eventImage.image=image;
    NSString *name;
    int random=arc4random()%100;
    name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@%d",[NSDate date],random];
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    event *e=[[event alloc]init];
    e.eventname=_eventLbl.text;
    e.eventime=time;